# Stanford POS Tagger - Dependency Between Windows & MapReduce (Linux)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I have the following method that returns a sentence with its POS Tag:

```
String Sentence = "STEERING COLUMN MOVES"
MaxentTagger taggerObject = new MaxentTagger("left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");
String TaggedSentence = getTaggedSentence(Sentence, taggerObject);
```

In the Windows environment the words "STEERING COLUMN" returns: NN NN (Which is Correct)
However, the same exact code implemented in MapReduce returns: VBG NN

For some reason, when I call this method in the Mapper class in MapReduce, it's tagging STEERING and COLUMN as separate objects/concepts instead of one.

90% of the objects tagged in MapReduce matches Windows.
10% are incorrect and 90% of the incorrect tags have the word STEERING in them.

Examples:

```
    Object           |      Windows     |      MapReduce (Linux)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
STEERING COLUMN      |       NN NN      |          VBG NN
STEERING WHEEL       |       NN NN      |          VBG NN
POWER STEERING       |       NN NN      |          NN VBG
```

Any guidance on debugging these discrepancies would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Tagger is more accurate in Java 8.

The Windows version was running in Java 8, while the MapReduce version was in Java 7.